# Converting effect size from linear and logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, linear, effect-size, standardized-mean-difference

I want to calculate a same effect size from a linear regression and a logistic regression to be able to compare them. More specifically, I would like to calculate standardized mean-difference (SMD).

I used the same variables (1 binary and 1 continous) for both linear and logistic regression when trying to check if my SMD calculation was right.
I thought that I would get the same SMD since it's the same variables but it is quite different (0.08 vs. 0.22).

Is it because my calculations are wrong or is it normal to have a different SMD since the models are different ?

Here's my converting formulas :

For logistic regression : In appendix A from this document https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.4073/cmpn.2016.3

```
effect_size_log <- function(OR) {
  es<-log(OR)*(sqrt(3)/pi)
  return(es) 
}
```

For linear regression : Equation (10) from this article https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17944619/

```
effect_size_lin<-function(t,n1,n2,df){
  numerator<-t*(n1+n2)
  denominator<-sqrt(n1*n2)*sqrt(df)
  es<-numerator/denominator
  return(es)
}
```

Here's my binary variable "var_b":

```
> table(data$var_b, useNA="always")

   0    1 <NA> 
1473  205   72
```

And my continuous variable "var_c":

```
> epi.descriptives(data$var_c)$a
     n       mean       sd       q25         q50      q75       lower      upper       min     max na
1 1750 0.01432374 1.558977 -1.057936 0.008730964 1.075398 -0.05876815 0.08741564 -4.102222 5.69762 16
```

From logistic regression :

```
> mod_1<-glm(data=data,var_b~var_c,family=binomial)
> odds.ratio(mod_1)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                        OR   2.5 % 97.5 %         p    
(Intercept)        0.13772 0.11832 0.1594 < 2.2e-16 ***
var_c              1.14924 1.04720 1.2613  0.003358 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> effect_size_log(1.14924)
[1] 0.07669032
```

From linear regression :

```
> mod_2<-glm(data=data,var_c~var_b,family=gaussian)
> summary(mod_2)

Call:
glm(formula = var_c ~ var_b, family = gaussian, data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.0808  -1.1124  -0.0588   1.0968   5.7190  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -0.02140    0.04081  -0.524  0.60004   
var_b          0.34258    0.11622   2.948  0.00325 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2.427819)

    Null deviance: 4053.7  on 1662  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4032.6  on 1661  degrees of freedom
  (87 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 6198.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> summary(mod_2[['model']]$var_b)
   0    1 
1458  205

> effect_size_lin(t=2.948,n1=1458,n2=205,df=1661)
[1] 0.2200286
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: You're comparing apples to butterflies: those effect sizes mean very different things.

Comment: @whuber Could you please elaborate? Both models give nearly the same pvalue, why a standardised effect size should be different?
SMD have the same scale for both models (small: 0.20-0.50; medium: 0.50–0.80; large: >0.80) so that means a logistic regression gives smaller SMD?
I saw these converting formulas were used to compare effect size in meta-analysis. So it can only be used to compare SMD between same type of models ?

Comment: The effects in the two models are completely different things that cannot be compared.  That the p-values might be similar says nothing.